# facebook chatbox persistence

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, rich-internet-application

As with facebook chatbox, when you turn to other facebook page while chatting, your page gets reloaded but chat window maintains state without reloading. How do they manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AJAX, they don't reload the whole page, just the necessary.

Actually, it's not AJAX, it's called BigPipe.

Comment: can you explain the structure / provide links where I can read more? Thanks in advance.